# in vs how to find a dialog's Corresponding file(.cpp) associated with it

Tags: visual-c++

in vs 2005 how to find a dialog's Corresponding file(.cpp) associated with it ? There used to be a key combination, which was hit when a particular form/dialogue is active.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try CRTL+F or CRTL+MAJ+F or CRTL+H or CRTL+MAJ+H.